# How to extract <a> from google scholar that contains link to download pdf file

Tags: java, netbeans, web-scraping

I need to extract the  tag from html of google scholar. I've written the script but it extracts all the 's. and I cant find any way to extract the specific tag where the download link of the paper is resting. Please Help.!
Below is the code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 Document doc;
        try {


            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?q=Bergmark%2C+D.+%282000%29.+Automatic+extraction+of+reference+linking+information+from+online+documents.+Technical+Report+CSTR2000-1821%2C+Cornell+Digital+Library+Research+Group&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5").get();


            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);


            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        // Elements link = doc.select(".pdf");
            for (Element link : links) {

                // get the value from href attribute
                System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
               System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here this is the structure of this tag :

```
<a href="https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/5809/2000-1821.pdf?sequence=1" data-clk="hl=en&amp;sa=T&amp;oi=gga&amp;ct=gga&amp;cd=0&amp;ei=YBMXWYbRO8a72Ab_2o24CQ"><span class="gs_ctg2">[PDF]</span> cornell.edu</a>
```

Comment: Show your code !!

Comment: Please have a look @!

Comment: Thank you for ur help..! It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `div.gs_ggsd` and `a[href]` as css query**

Here

```
div.gs_ggsd => Select all the div Tag that have class name gs_ggsd
```

Example :

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?q=Bangla+Speech+Recognition")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
            .get();

    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);

    Elements links = doc.select("div.gs_ggsd").select("a[href]");

    for (Element link : links) {
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Read More : https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: free of errors and exceptions but no output, is it because of the h3?? if tht is the case, its nt an option..! because my system will download multiple papers, and there must be a way that every unpaid ppr's download link must b extracted.!

Comment: @farooqahmed Answer Updated